# Keep initial input signal of enabled subsystem constant during pulse

Tags: matlab, simulink

Imagine I have a continous signal (e.g. a sine) and a periodic rectangular pulse (50%) (**blue lines**):

[image]

While the pulse is switching its state - and a little before and after (**yellow line, 2nd plot**) - I'd like the continious signal to remain constant. So when the second pulse = 1, there should be a little stair step in the original signal.

**How can I implement this behaviour in Simulink?**

---

I thought a simple **Zero Order Hold** within an enabled subsystem should be enough, but it returns the output from the *previous enabled state*, which is a little weird (**yellow line, 1st plot**).

[**Here you can find a minimal example to play with.**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3u428w0dwks3uoc/test.slx?dl=0):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your enabled subsysten with a triggerd subsystem / raising edge. Don't put any block in it, just leave the input connected to the output.

[image]

Comment: I'd guessed it was that simple, and I still don't understand why. Is the triggered subsystem just active for this very little moment, when it's triggered? I thought it would be active from the time of triggering until the end.

Comment: The triggered subsystem is evaluated once per (raising /falling) edge.